# Can't execute query on database anymore

Tags: codenameone

I don't know why but I can't execute any request on my SQLite DB anymore.

It's throw this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEDatabase.executeQuery(SEDatabase.java:195)
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effectively means the connection is closed so the value is null. There are additional lines there which should lead to the line of code. At that point in your code the connection would have been closed by someone.